# JSF rich select setting component width

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, width, html-select

Simple and clean...
I can set the listWidth (for the dropdown elements), but I cannot set the component width, also using inline style...

```
<rich:select                        
 enableManualInput="true"
 clientFilterFunction="customFilter"
 value="#{listaPrestazioni.filterLiv1}"
 style="width: 80px;"> 
      <f:selectItems value="#{listaPrestazioni.liv1List}"/>
      <a4j:ajax event="change" render="tab_dettaglio" execute="@this" />
</rich:select>
```

I want my select to be at maximum 80px width..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<h:outputStylesheet>
     .MarcxSelectStyle input{
       width: 80px;
     }
</h:outputStylesheet>

<rich:select ... styleClass="MarcxSelectStyle">...</rich:select>
```

Comment: With RichFaces 4.5.0A at least (not tested on previous), this doesn't work, you need to use `.MarcxSelectStyle input.rf-sel-inp` selector to override RichFaces CSS. Also, `width: 100%` will not work without other changes.

Answer (score 0):

i had this issue and the solution for me was to use ths jsf tag , which seems to do the job for me , anyway this might help somebody :

```
<h:selectOneListbox id="myListBox" style="width:100%" size="1">
      <f:selectItems value="#{MyController.bean.items}" />
</h:selectOneListbox>
```